# Attempted to call function "apcu_fetch" from namespace "Doctrine\Common\Cache"

Tags: angular, symfony, angular5, apc, php-7.2

I'm developping an application with symfony 3 and **angular** **5**. my system is windows 10 and i'm using php7.2

All is done wih dev_mode, but when i'm turning on production mode i'm having this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException:
>   Attempted to call function "apcu_fetch" from namespace
>   "Doctrine\Common\Cache".

How can i install apcu ?

Comment: Can you share your config_prod.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 7.x it would seem Symfony have removed the framework (validation and serializer) cache config in their default [`config_prod.yml`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/ebe2bad/app/config/config_prod.yml) and kept the ORM cache but using `apc` instead of `apcu` as they did previously. I saw the same issue on a project running on PHP 7.1.12 that I had started before this change.

I did manage to get APCU running by installing it and modifying the Symfony prod config but I would be inclined to do as Symfony do on this one. In case you are thinking of still using APCU and serialization & validator caching:

Install it on the server if it's not installed (this will vary from server to server but there are other articles out there explaining this):

```
pecl install apcu && echo "extension=apcu.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/apcu.ini
```

Then in your `services.yml` add the following to configure the validator cache:

```
services:
    doctrine.cache.apcu:
        class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcuCache

    validator.mapping.cache.doctrine.apcu:
        class: Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\Cache\DoctrineCache
        arguments: ['@doctrine.cache.apcu']
```

Then use that in your `config_prod.yml`:

```
framework:
    validation:
        cache: validator.mapping.cache.doctrine.apcu
    serializer:
        cache: doctrine.cache.apcu

doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apcu
        query_cache_driver: apcu
        result_cache_driver: apcu
```